# How to Use Intellij idea14.0.2 to Debug the golang？

Tags: intellij-idea, go

The Debug button is disable, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> will show this:

[image: debug button is disabled]

How to properly configure  the debug page?

[image: the confige page]

Answer (score 10):

Update. The Go plugin supports Delve on Linux and Mac since September 2015 and on Windows since January 2016.

Original answer:

Currently we are dropping support for the debugger with gdb as it's very hard to use and unstable. Please see [the go docs for gdb debugging](https://golang.org/doc/gdb)

However, there are efforts in getting [the open-source Delve debugger](https://github.com/derekparker/delve)  [support for IDEs](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/pull/57) from which IDEA will benefit as well.

Please bug the Go team to support Delve or another debugger in order to have a stable solution and then integration with IDEA could be done.

Comment: @disniper can you provide steps in installing the `Delve` in linux

Comment: There is no need to install Delve manually, it's bundled with the plugin.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

thanks ,solved it. 
Intellij Config is not right

Comment: So the PR 644 I mention in the answer was the exact cause of your issue?

Answer (score 1):

The debug feature was introduced by [issue 25](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/25), and [commit 3a21e14](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/commit/3a21e14a9807f6c51ee5bca308a50f15eaa01e9d)

> The correct way is to implement the debugger interfaces in inteliij and to hook them to a running gdb process.

(Here is an [example of manually calling gdb to debug a Go program](http://thornydev.blogspot.com/2014/01/debugging-go-golang-programs-with-gdb.html); using the options `-c -gcflags '-N -l'`: not sure if the `-l` would matter as it is missing from the OP's screenshot "`Go builder arguments`")

It is possible the debug button is disabled if no gcc is configure for the Go debug process to use.

Note also that since [PR 644](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/pull/644):

> "Debug" is disabled, if "Build Before run" is not enabled.
>   This should fix the problem, when `gdb` wants to run a not existing executable, because the `outputDir` is not set.

Comment: Here is another case where Debug is disabled: https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/pull/657

Comment: I looked this ,but when I set the params '-l' the Intellij will show Finished building project F:\goproj\GitTest.git\trunk\src\test1\bin/newPackage.exe
C:/Go/bin/go.exe build -o F:\goproj\GitTest.git\trunk\src\test1\bin/newPackage.exe -gcflags - -l' newPackage/
flag provided but not defined: -l'

Comment: @Eric not just `- -l`: `-N -l`

Comment: you are the man, after setting the `outputDir` debugger is working